# Disable / Enable primefaces keyFilter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, keyfilter

I have an keyFilter to my p:inputMask i want to disable and enable the keyFilter

```
<div class="col-sm-6 #{(newDesWeb eq '_')?'input-group' : ''} errorCible"  >
                <p:inputMask  inputStyleClass="#{(newDesWeb eq '_')? 'selectfile' : 'form-control lg200 input-sm'}  errorCible"
                    id="zoneResidenceAssure" styleClass="#{(newDesWeb eq '_')? 'ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched' : ''}  errorCible"
                    style="width: 100%"
                    value="#{devisPresBean.currentAssureDevisBean.adresseActuelle.zipCode}" maxlength="#{msg['form.control.input.codepostal.maxlength']}">
                    <c:passThroughAttribute name="fieldId" value="LIBDEVzoneResidenceAssure" />
                    <c:ajax onevent="displayAjaxSatus" event="change" execute="@this" render="@this" />
                </p:inputMask>
                <p:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9_]/i" for="zoneResidenceAssure" />
                <bpsi:message for="zoneResidenceAssure" />
                 
            </div>
```

I want with a condition disable the `p:keyFilter`

Comment: Tried setting rendered to false conditionally?

Comment: write your condition as js function and use testFunction on keyfilter https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/keyfilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in 3 way:

1. use rendered on `<p:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9_]/i" for="zoneResidenceAssure" rendered="#{backing.condition()}"/>` but then ypu need to update the container of keyFilter be it a form or a panel on the condition change.
2. use a dynamic regex like `<p:keyFilter regEx="#{backing.regex()}" for="zoneResidenceAssure" />` and update the `keyFilter` on every condition change, returning actual pattern if you want it enabled or empty string to disable it.
3. use `testFunction` on the `keyFilter` instead of `regEx` and implement the condition in JavaScript as a test function.